# WPF Toolkit editable combobox

Tags: combobox, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to implement an editable combobox in a WPFTOOLKIT datagrid. The user must have the possibility to type a new value. Binding is made with MVVM.
Everything works well except this issue : after typing a new value, the value is lost when going out of the combo.

Here is my XAML code :

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="FlangeType"  Title="Flange Type"  Width="80" >

    <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
          <xcdg:CellEditor>
                <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path= DataContext.FlangeTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                                            SelectedValue="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}"
                                            Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentDrumStandard.FlangeType,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                            IsEditable="True"/>
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
              </xcdg:CellEditor>
      </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>

</xcdg:Column>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I was missing the RelativeSource for the Text property.

Updated code :

```
                                <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                                    <xcdg:CellEditor>
                                        <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ComboBox
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FlangeTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                                                    SelectedValue="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}"
                                                    Text="{Binding DataContext.CurrentDrumStandard.FlangeType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                                    IsEditable="True"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                                    </xcdg:CellEditor>
                                </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>

                            </xcdg:Column>
```